# Array filter cause infinite $digest loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two collections of objects. One of them have objects with primitive values, another one with objects values.

I need to render collection in html table with dynamic columns. I have made a filter for this, but it's work for collection with primitive object value and cause infinite $digest loop(see console) for collection with objects.

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zohaca/6/edit?console,output)

I understand that problem is in returning a new object each time due to angular.copy. But why does it work for primitive value?

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question but because there are many similar questions without answers in SO I decided to post my answer.

The key to solving the problem is fact that ng-repeat don't use neither $watch nor $watch with Equality. It uses $watchCollection to watch collection =). In my case when filter returns new copied object with primitive values $watchCollection doesn't fire(standard $watch do in this case) so I avoid infinite $digest loop. But in case object with object value $watchCollection triggers infinite $digest loop($watch with Equality=true doesn't).

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zohaca/11/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it works for primitives is JS passes primitives by value, rather than by reference. The problem can be solved with lodash's (the _ library) memoize function. [This page](http://www.terrencewatson.com/2014/06/28/memoize/) details the exact problem and solution using memoize.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there isn't the same situation in my case. I always make angular.copy() in my filter either object has primitive values or objects values.  My filter always yield a new object and because var a = {a:11, b:12, c:13, d:14}; angular.copy(a) === angular.copy(a) -> false  it should trigger $digest loop, but it don't. It triggers $digest loop only if var a = {a:11, b:12, c:{...}, d:14}.

Comment: angular.copy("1") === angular.copy("1") returns true. === behaves differently depending on what is being compared; it compares values for primitives and compares references (the memory address I believe, but it might be something related to JS's hashing system) of objects.

Comment: yes, i know it, but my filter never yield a primitive it yield an object with primitive values so it should trigger $digest.

Comment: in any case it was useful to know about memoize function, thanks.